# Deleting data from tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-delete

It may be that I've spent too long looking at this today so being stupid.
But........

I have a simple stored procedure which does this;

```
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DELETE FROM ProductLoading
END
```

The table `ProductLoading` consists of 3 fields, non of which are key fields. It is a temporary table which needs to have data in it for a short while when data is loading from seperate datafeeds. I do this to check products for deletion.

Now when this code is run, **it also deletes everything from another table**, `Products3`.
If I comment this line out, it doesn't.

Not an expert on keys and indexes but have a basic grasp.
But having looked at both tables, cannot see any dependencies.
Plus when I run an execution plan, it doesn't make any reference to `Products3` table.

Really stuck on this one.
Anybody educate me on what I am overlooking.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like [Cascading Referential Integrity Constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186973%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).  Are you certain that one of the 3 fields in `ProductLoading` is not a key?

Comment: Just looked at the ProductLoading table and there are no keys there. I just use the 3 fields to store the information so I can use that info to cross check against the Products3 table later on. No constraints. No indexes. No triggers. Really confusing me.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what glitch happened.

But after much head puzzling, basically added a dummy insert statement into the stored procedure and recompiled it.

Bizarrely the delete statement then didn't filter upto the Products3 table.

I then deleted this dummy insert statement and even more bizarrely the stored procedure continued to work.

Now the only thing that was different was way back when, the tables were created with the wrong schema. I realised this immediately and recreated the tables under the correct schema and deleted the wrongly created tables. No data was present at this point so not sure if anything was corrupted during this. Can't see how, but hey, 1's and 0's can sometimes not add up.

So no solution as such, just one of li

Answer (score 0):

ProductLoading loading must contain a primary key that is a foreign key to another table with cascading delete enabled.

[image]

Comment: If it is a table whose usefulness is temporary, then it could be that the FK(s) causing the cascade are, too.

Comment: Hey, jonnyGold, G Aletras here ;-)

Comment: I was just talking about you at lunch today.  The universe is awesome.

Comment: No keys, indexes, triggers or constraints on ProductLoading table. Very simple holding table for use in cross checking products later on. And the reason it's Products3 is because I set it up after I thought Products2 table might be corrupted. But same result. Execution plan only has reference to deleting and scanning of ProductLoading table. No reference to Products3 in there

Comment: Just before this stored procedure, I run a seperate stored procedure which does this.
Gets all products from the Products3 table and cross references them against the ProductLoading table. If the product on the Products3 table doesn't now exist on the ProductLoading table then it's no longer in the live feed. So I delete it.
Originally I had the DELETE FROM ProductLoading in this stored procedure but then took it into a seperate stored procedure in case any mis-reference was hanging around. But result is still the same.

Comment: The only thing that stops the products from being deleted from Products3 table is to comment out the DELETE FROM ProductLoading. But this defeats the object of clearing out the ProductLoading table!!! Going mad!

Answer (score 0):

In theory your table ProductLoading could have a trigger for delete?

Comment: I've said it before and I'll say it again: triggers are bad, m'kay... like a ping-pong ball thrown into a room full of mousetraps.

Comment: Let's say I haven't use them for a long time! ;-)

Comment: No trigger. Nor keys, indexes or constraints. Just 3 basic fields to store loaded product info so I can cross check it later on.

Comment: In management studio you can right click The table to use script as new table feature perhaps when you do this you find more info in THE generated table schema?

Comment: Thanks Joost. Doing this gives me following;
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductLoading](
 [pc] [varchar](50) NULL,
 [ami] [int] NULL,
 [ri] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

Is this null [PRIMARY] causing an issue? Or is that always present?

Comment: As an extra confusion. If I run my first stored procedure which adds data to the ProductLoading table and stop it. Then manually type in the command DELETE FROM Productloading...................the Products3 data is unaffected. It only seems to be when I run this stored procedure with the same delete command in it, that it deletes the data in Products3. Never seen behaviour like this before in my 10+ years developing.

Comment: Hi for now it makes no sense to me too thats weird behaviour!